# Meteor Easy-Search tags

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm coding a web application where users can create posts which are characterized through the use of tags. 
When searching for posts a user can add a tag to filter the search.

To accomplish the above, I'm using, https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search

I'm using code similar to the one found in http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/docs/recipes/

When a new tag is added an event is triggered and the following code is ran

```
            var instance = EasySearch.getComponentInstance(
                    { index : 'suggestions' }
                );
            EasySearch.changeProperty('suggestions', 'Tags', x);
            instance.triggerSearch();
```

In another file I have written this code:

```
Suggestions.initEasySearch('name');

EasySearch.createSearchIndex('name', {
    'field' : ['name'],
    'collection' : Suggestions,
    'props' : {
        'tags' : []
    },
    'query' : function (searchString) {
        // Default query that will be used for searching
        var query = EasySearch.getSearcher(this.use).defaultQuery(this, searchString);

        // filter for categories if set
        if (this.props.tags.length > 0) {
            query.tags =  {field: {$in: this.props.tags}}
        }

        return query;
    }
});
```

The code simply isn't working. I'm not getting any errors but the search results are exactly the same as before adding the code shown above.

Also, it might be important to know what a post (suggestion) looks like.

```
{
            name: title,
            score: 0,
            description: description,
            tags : tags,
            createdBy: Meteor.userId(),
            createdAt: new Date(),
            username: Meteor.user().username
        }
```